# Remove cast iron wood stove

Tags: masonry, chimney, demolition, woodstove

New homeowner here and we would like to remove a cast iron wood stove and the brick structure with minimal damage to the hardwood floor below (see picture below). Two options:

1) Hire someone. We already contacted multiple builders but they basically don't call back or don't have time. One came by for something else but now shows no sign of being interested in the job. We don't even know whether this is a job for a builder. The guy who came by said demolition expert but isn't that overkill?

2) DIY. What are the steps? Is this doable? Does the chimney has to be sealed off?

ps: Any thoughts on whether the hardwood floor below is intact would be appreciated. Everyone says something else.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that is a hardwood floor. Sure looks a lot like pine.

Comment: Are you intending on just removing the stove and the flat pad under it? Or are you considering removing all of the vertical part up the wall? If the latter does this brick structure extend all the way up through the roof as a chimney?

Comment: I doubt the wood floor extends under the brick pad.  You need to find a way to fix this floor. You seem to have very long boards which add to the challenge of hiding the cut lines

Comment: It's hard to tell but it appears as though that pad was added when someone added the cast iron stove to the fireplace, but it's really hard to tell from here. If so, and they left the wood floor there, it's likely ruined. If not and it was removed or never there, matching it to the old floor will be next to impossible. That's likely why you can't find anyone interested, they know you will not like the outcome and it might result in not getting paid.